# Can rsync be used to resume transfer after other transfer/download methods?

Tags: rsync

So basically can I use rsync to resume the transfer of the file(s)/directory which was initially started by another program (wget, curl, scp, ftp, ...)?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. But for best performance you should pay attention to the options you use.

When downloading files, take care to preserve file modification times. File synchronization utilities normally assume that if the source file and the destination file have the same size and the same modification time, then they have the same content. This speeds up synchronization of multiple files significantly. If the modification times are different then rsync has to read the content on both sides to decide whether to transfer the file.

- With `wget`, use `-N` (`--timestamping`).
- With `curl`, use `-R` (`--remote-time`).
- With `cp`, `scp`, use `-p` (or `-a` for GNU `cp`).
- With `rsync`, use `-t` or `-a`. (You should always use `rsync -a` unless you understand why it isn't desirable in a particular case.)
- FTP programs usually copy the timestamp.
- You can tell rsync to assume that the source file and the destination file are identical if they have the same size, by passing the `--size-only` option. This is ok if the only way the file gets modified is to grow it by adding data at the end, in which case you should probably also pass the `--append` option. But if the file can get modified in other ways then `--size-only` is not safe: you could miss modifications if they happen not to change the file size.

If you use plain `rsync -a` then:

- Files that don't exist in the destination are simply copied.
- Files that exist in the destination but have a different timestamp or a different size are copied. Rsync will try to minimize the amount of transferred data through its delta-transfer algorithm, which saves transfers if the files have identical parts.
- Files that exist in the destination and have the same timestamp and size are skipped.

If you're sure that the files on the two sides are either identical or truncated copies then you can pass the `--append` option. With this option, rsync assumes that any file in the destination is a partial or complete copy and will directly append missing data to shorter files, without checking that the beginning of the file is the same on both sides. This is faster but more fragile.